# How to get slice of UTF-8 symbols in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have just begun to learn Rust and can not understand how to get the slice.

```rust
let word = "Хороший"; // I want to get last two symbols.
// word[word.len()-2..] // I understand that is not working because it is not byte array.

let chars = word.chars();
let v = chars.skip(chars.count() - i).map(|x| x).collect();

// But I don't know how to convert 'v' to &str type and do I need it at all?
```

How does the task get solved in Rust? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) to get correct offsets. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1662db8ff43d05dc4474edd8d1c7afec)

```rs
let word = "Хороший"; // I want to get last two symbols.
let mut chars = word.char_indices();
let index_of_last_two = chars.nth_back(1).unwrap().0; // 1 because 0 is й and 1 is и
let slice_of_last_two = &word[index_of_last_two..];
```

Comment: Thanks very much! 

Would you explain or give a link to ".0" - the syntax element? What is it?

Comment: It's a tuple index https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html

Answer (score -1):

You can't convert `v` to an `&str`, it's an owned thing (vector?) of `char`, which are 32b unicode scalar values.

The first attempt is close to working, but because of the way indexes work `word[word.len()-2..]` will return an `str`, which is an *unsized type*, which is complicated to work with.

But all you have to do is reference it, [as shown in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-SliceIndex%3Cstr%3E-for-RangeFrom%3Cusize%3E).

And also as documented, also as documented:

- indexing str works in terms of code units (UTF8 bytes), because `й` is two bytes in UTF8 (`d0b9`) an index of -2 will return just that
- if the slice does starts or ends anywhere but the start of an encoded codepoint, it'll panic

So generally speaking, indexing directly with hardcoded offset tends not to be the best idea. What usually works better is pattern searches (matches and friends), using [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) so you know where to slice, and possibly using the [`as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) method of `chars` or `char_indices`.